# jquery Fancybox update content on form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, fancybox, modal-dialog

I've got a fancybox modal that holds an ajax contact form. When I submit it, I'd like for the results of the form to post directly in the fancybox, but instead it is going directly to the .php page.

Switching the type from ajax to iframe isn't an option, as this is already on a live website with a lot of code already and place that would require changing thousands of img and css links to absolute addresses.

I'm not great with jquery, so could anyone assist me with the code I'll need to use to accomplish this?

Comment: The ajax itself is a script that's a little over 3000 lines of a code(the contact form is part of a page with tons of other forms/form handling built in).  This once worked in another modal, but the site owner wanted to change to fancybox. What information do you need? I can try to pick out the information from the script.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just the jQuery aspect of the code; the `$.ajax` part.